# Pandas groupby.agg count returns wrong count

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I'm trying to count rows by 3 columns (county,year and month),

data is very simple

| year | month | date | county |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 2 | 20240204 | Taoyuan |
| 2024 | 2 | 20240224 | Chiayi |
| 2024 | 1 | 20240118 | Kaoshung |
| 2024 | 2 | 20240213 | Xinchu |
| 2024 | 2 | 20240203 | Taichung |

but the code like below

```
output_data = input_data.groupby(["county","year","month"]).agg({'count': ['count']})
```

and this code

```
output_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data.groupby(["county","year","month"])['count'].count())
```

have different results.

The results of these two is like

| county | year | month | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023 | 1 | 106 |
| B | 2023 | 1 | 44 |
| C | 2023 | 1 | 117 |
| D | 2023 | 1 | 60 |
| E | 2023 | 1 | 80 |

| county | year | month | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023 | 1 | 106 |
| B | 2023 | 1 | 48 |
| C | 2023 | 1 | 118 |
| D | 2023 | 1 | 60 |
| E | 2023 | 1 | 83 |

Any ideas?

Comment: are there NaNs in your data? please include the data in your question

Comment: hi, i have fill nan with data.fillna(0, inplace=True) before counting

Comment: What is the result if you skip the `fillna`?

Comment: i found it'll be right if i change the first code into output_data = input_data.groupby(["county","year","month"]).agg({'count': ['sum']})

Comment: The there is a difference between count and size.  Count ignores NaN values.

Comment: Either my pandas version is vastly different or you are mixing up `count` and `county` in key parts of your code - or hide that the input frame already has a column `count`.